# Error logging in to store with Shopify CLI

Tags: ruby, openssl, shopify, homebrew

I'm having an issue logging into my store to start local development. This is the first time I'm attempting this using Shopify CLI.

When running `shopify login --store={myStoreName}.myshopify.com` I get this error:

```
✗ An unexpected error occured.
    To submit an issue include the stack trace.
    To print the stack trace, add the environment variable SHOPIFY_CLI_STACKTRACE=1.

** [Bugsnag] 2022-03-16 14:23:24 +0100: Unable to send information to Bugsnag (https://notify.bugsnag.com), #<OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed (unable to get local issuer certificate)>
** [Bugsnag] 2022-03-16 14:23:24 +0100: ["/Users/Tea/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/net/protocol.rb:46:in `connect_nonblock'", "/Users/Tea/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/net/protocol.rb:46:in `ssl_socket_connect'", "/Users/Tea/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/net/http.rb:1038:in `connect'", "/Users/Tea/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/net/http.rb:970:in `do_start'", "/Users/Tea/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/net/http.rb:959:in `start'", "/Users/Tea/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/net/http.rb:1512:in `request'", "/Users/Tea/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bugsnag-6.24.2/lib/bugsnag/delivery/synchronous.rb:51:in `request'", "/Users/Tea/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bugsnag-6.24.2/lib/bugsnag/delivery/synchronous.rb:12:in `deliver'", "/Users/Tea/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bugsnag-6.24.2/lib/bugsnag/delivery/thread_queue.rb:38:in `block in serialize_and_deliver'", "/Users/Tea/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bugsnag-6.24.2/lib/bugsnag/delivery/thread_queue.rb:55:in `block (2 levels) in start_once!'"]
Copy
```

From what I understand this should open a login window in my browser but instead I get this error. I do get the login page when I just do `shopify login`. I then log in but nothing changes because I'm not connected to my specific store. `shopify whoami` says I'm not logged in.

I've tried reinstalling everything, researching about OpenSSL certificates, shopify CLI info, and following countless tutorials to what I think might be the problem and I just end up with the same error every time.

Operating System: macOS

Shell: zsh

Ruby version (ruby -v): 3.0.3

Anyone encounter this before or could you point me to something that could help? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into similar issue, from what I can clearly see in your code, you won't need that `=` in the command

```html
shopify login --store yourstore.myshopify.com
```

That alone should solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

The login command doesn't exist anymore. You can run shopify theme dev --store YOUR_STORE to login into a store. Check this page: https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/tools/cli#connecting-to-a-store

maybe it will help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you encounter the above error while logging in, it is because the url is a live site with ".com", you shouldn't use a live site for logging in.

The actual URL is found in :

Login to your store admin>Go to "**Setting**" on the left bottom of the panel>Go to "**Domains**". You will find a url with **.myshopify.com** extension, login to that url using shopify-cli.

Thanks.